# Как выполнить процедуру типа "procedure TForm1.input(s: string);" из таймера?

Tags: delphi

Нужно что-то такое:

```
public
procedure input(s:string);

procedure TForm1.input(s: string);
begin
  Timer5.Enabled:=True;
  //bot.parce(s);
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer5Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Timer5.Enabled:=False;
    bot.parce(s);
end;
```

Имею ошибку Undeclared identifier: 's'

Comment: >Имею ошибку Undeclared identifier: 's'

я бы не стал этому сильно удивляться, поскольку s у вас действительно не объявлена

Comment: Можно, конечно, объявить s, но требуется именно выполнение этой процедуры.

Comment: @hkpp ну так выполняйте. Вы же ее не вызываете нигде. Вместо этого вы пишете заведомо ошибочный код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private
  PrivateS: string;
public
  procedure input(s:string);

implementation

procedure TForm1.input(s: string);
begin
  PrivateS := s;
  Timer5.Enabled:=True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer5Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Timer5.Enabled:=False;
    bot.parce(PrivateS);
end;
```

**Это может быть очень плохим решением.** Напишите подробнее, какую задачу вы пытаетесь решить с помощью таймера. Наверняка можно сделать по-другому.